# How to display Apache FTP server messages

Tags: java, apache, ftp, server

I have an application with embedded Apache FTP server. I want to be able to print out server messages like "User X connected to the server", "User X transferred file Y" etc. 
How can I achieve this functionality?

Comment: I read Apache Documentation, but couldn't find anything regarding reply message management. I was looking for some event handlers like onUserConnected(), but it seems they do not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you'll want to extend [DefaultFtplet](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/apache/ftpserver/ftplet/DefaultFtplet.html), log methods you like and pass all along the chain.

Check out the configuration example on [FTP Server home page](http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver-project/ftplet.html).

Comment: Thank you very much, that is exactly what I was looking for!